# How to predict %health percentage values for regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

[image: kneighbors test prediction result]I am currently working on the a predictive maintenance dataset, that contains data from sensors, the occurrence of any errors and some characteristics of each machine. After feature engineering i have created a column that contains the %percentage of the remaining useful life of an engine.

The y_column is a series of even increasing 0 to 1 variables that go back to 0 when 1 is reached (which indicates the occurrence of an error). I am using regression models and my results look like the following images. Since i am new to ML what is the approach on this type of problems? I am more used to classification. What are the ways to improve this type of results?

I have added rolling mean/std/min/max, i have added lag features, i have copied some techniques used in classification approaches of this dataset but even though i get a RMSE and MAE of 20% it doesn't capture the image of the problem correctly. I am using GradientBoostingRegressor KNeighborsRegressor RandomForestRegressor so far. What are some general techniques to improve my results? By the way the models are fit without any hyper parameter tuning. Any advice on this type of results?